# How to get async result in main thread

Tags: windows-phone-7

I'm making a login page on Windows Phone 7 app. I'd like to get login error status code on the login page when login error message return from server on async thread.

So my question is :
In bellow code sample, please let me know how do you get "responseString(string)" in Main method?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.begingetrequeststream.aspx

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;

class HttpWebRequestBeginGetRequest
{
    private static ManualResetEvent allDone = new ManualResetEvent(false);

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {


        // Create a new HttpWebRequest object.
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://www.contoso.com/example.aspx");

        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

        // Set the Method property to 'POST' to post data to the URI.
        request.Method = "POST";

        // start the asynchronous operation
        request.BeginGetRequestStream(new AsyncCallback(GetRequestStreamCallback), request);

        // Keep the main thread from continuing while the asynchronous
        // operation completes. A real world application
        // could do something useful such as updating its user interface. 
        allDone.WaitOne();

        /* I'd like to get "responseString" here. */
    }

    private static void GetRequestStreamCallback(IAsyncResult asynchronousResult)
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)asynchronousResult.AsyncState;

        // End the operation
        Stream postStream = request.EndGetRequestStream(asynchronousResult);

        Console.WriteLine("Please enter the input data to be posted:");
        string postData = Console.ReadLine();

        // Convert the string into a byte array.
        byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);

        // Write to the request stream.
        postStream.Write(byteArray, 0, postData.Length);
        postStream.Close();

        // Start the asynchronous operation to get the response
        request.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(GetResponseCallback), request);
    }

    private static void GetResponseCallback(IAsyncResult asynchronousResult)
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)asynchronousResult.AsyncState;

        // End the operation
        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.EndGetResponse(asynchronousResult);
        Stream streamResponse = response.GetResponseStream();
        StreamReader streamRead = new StreamReader(streamResponse);
        string responseString = streamRead.ReadToEnd(); /* I'd like to get this responseString in Main method. */
        Console.WriteLine(responseString);
        // Close the stream object
        streamResponse.Close();
        streamRead.Close();

        // Release the HttpWebResponse
        response.Close();
        allDone.Set();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You could just define `responseString` as a class-level variable instead of defining it within the `GetResponseCallback` method. That way, it can be accessed from anywhere in the class, rather than just the method scope.

To navigate to another page from a background thread, you can use a `Dispatcher`.

```
    //Method to move to next page. Can be called from GetResponseCallBack
    private void NavigateToNextPage()
    {
        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
        {
           NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("Page2.xaml", UriKind.Relative"));
        });
    }
```

Comment: I'm sorry. I forgot to write that the code will hang in "allDone.WaitOne();". I don't know why but it seems to happen this issue if I use the code in Windows Phone app. So I can't use your advice.

Comment: @okame - Is there a reason you want to block the main thread, whilst using an async method? Also, are you getting a response successfully?

Comment: Yes. I want to stop to wait async thread. I wait async thead result, then going to next page if login succeeded.

Comment: There are two things that come to mind. Firstly, you can call a method that will navigate to the next page from within your `GetResponseCallBack` method. The navigation should be done on the UI thread (updated answer). Or, you could use a WebClient instead of HttpWebRequest since a WebClient will block the UI thread anyway.

Comment: Oh, that's a nice idea! I'll try it!