# Threading Wp7 in comparison with Android

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I'm porting an Android app to Windows Phone 7, and while perusing through the System.Threading namespace docs and various tutorials and examples on the web, I am still missing some tidbits.

What I have learned so far:

1, To create a thread and execute a function on that thread:

```
    using System.Threading;

    ...

    Thread newThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(MyMethod()));
    newThread.Start();
```

2, To synchronize objects (analogous to Android's synchronized() keyword):

```
    lock(this)
    {
      // Do synchronized stuff here.
    }
```

What I am missing:

3, How can I call a delegate from my worker thread *on the calling thread*? By "calling thread" I mean the thread that created my worker thread, not the worker thread itself. For example, on Android I would do the following (which would call it on the main ui thread, also an acceptable solution):

```
    Message.obtain(m_messageHandler, message, null).sendToTarget();
```

I have found [AsyncCallback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6563882/how-to-get-async-result-in-main-thread). Does this do what I need it to? Anyone have an example? It's not very clear as to what thread calls the callback routine.

4, On Android, the worker thread can do a wait() to pause until the calling thread calls interrupt(). This is similar to an Event and WaitForObject() in win32. For example on Android:

```
    // Worker thread does:
    synchronized (this)
    {
      wait();
    }

    ...

    // Main thread calls:
    synchronized(this) 
    {
      if(m_thread != null)
      {
        // Interrupt any wait()s.
        m_thread.interrupt();
      }
    }
```

As soon as the thread is interrupted, the worker thread continues executing after the wait() call. Great for service-type threads.

Any guidance on #3 and #4 would be much appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another way to kick something off on another thread is

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(state => {
  // do work here
}, myStateObjectOrNull);
```

I find this syntax easier than creating a `Thread`.

To so work back on the UI thread, which is essential for anthing that will update the UI, you need a handle to the `Dispatcher`. The easiest way to get one is as follows

```
Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => {
  // do work here
});
```

You can not `wait` on WP7. You need to work with callbacks, events or Reactive Extensions. There are a couple of ways through the API where you can write code that waits, but it will just lock up the app and the waiting prevents the code it is waiting for to run.

Comment: I will give the Dispatcher a try. Looking at the docs for this and the examples, looks like exactly what I need. I need to progress in my project with more ui to test this out, so i won't mark anything as answered just yet until i've done so... I'm not so crazy about the lambda expression; i need to encapsulate the thread object etc. And as far as waiting goes, I'm talking about waiting on worker threads, not on the main ui thread (which would lock up the app of course).

Answer (score 1):

The Silverlight equivalent of a Win32 event is either the [`ManualResetEvent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.manualresetevent(v=VS.95).aspx) or [`AutoResetEvent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.autoresetevent(v=VS.95).aspx) depending on your needs.

As Richard may have been attempting to suggest, the [`Monitor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.monitor_methods(v=VS.95).aspx) class also provides similar wait/signal semantics. I tend to think of a monitor as controlling access to a resource, though, while events just let you know that something happened.

Comment: `Marshal.Wait` / `Marshal.Pulse` might also be what he wants for #4

Comment: Actually, I think AutoResetEvent does exactly what I need for #4, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Eventually you have to check out the [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) class. 
I think it's the same as the [AsyncTask](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) class in Android. BackgroundWorker contains two events: One is called to do the work in another thread and the completed event will be called in the  UI thread.

```
var worker = new BackgroundWorker();
worker.DoWork += delegate { ... };
worker.RunWorkerCompleted += delegate { ... };
worker.RunWorkerAsync();
```